# How to fix ICS-file so O365 wont send notifications to google-calender

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I´ve imported an ics-link from O365 in google calendar that´s working fine and sends notifications from job O365 calender to my private google calendar.

But now I want to delete the sync so it stops sending me automatic notifications to my google calendar that I can´t turn off.

I have tried this:

- Turned off the notification function in O365.
- Can't find any way to turn it off in the Gmail setting, 
  can only find an import button there for ics files.
- I´ve tried to ask the question in Gmail support forums without any reply for 1 month.

I think I need to edit a new ics-file and import it to make I stop?
How do I do that when I have opened it in the text editor?
What value do I change to make it stop period?
The code is pretty long so I didn't attached it but I can if so is needed.

Kind Regards
/Beginner